# Bash rename zips in subdirectories

Tags: bash, rename, loops, mv

Hi have a bunch of folders with one zip file in it the paths look like this

```
/folder/subfolder/archive.zip
/folder/subfolder1/archive1.zip
/folder/subfolder2/archive2.zip
/folder/subfolder3/zip3.zip
/folder/subfolder4/zip4.zip
etc...
```

I need the out put to be like this

```
/folder/subfolder/preview.zip
/folder/subfolder1/preview.zip
/folder/subfolder2/preview.zip
/folder/subfolder3/preview.zip
/folder/subfolder4/preview.zip
etc...
```

Each folder also only has one zip in it so i don't have to work about overwriting and what not i just need each zip in each folder renamed to preview.zip no matter the name in each subdirectory how can i do that in bash?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
for j in **/*.zip; do mv "$j" "${j%/*.zip}/preview.zip"; done
```

As pointed out by SiegeX, note that to use recursive globbing you've got to set the [`globstar`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar) option and that is only available in bash 4.x

Comment: Don't forget to mention that this wont work on many implementations, because it's a Bash 4.X only feature, also you didn't say anything about enabling globstar

Comment: How does this cope with whitespace in filenames?

Comment: @Johnsyweb poorly, because he didn't quote his variables

Comment: @SiegeX: A rhetorical question ;)

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thanks for your comment. I've added the missing quotes and now that case would be handled.

Comment: @jcollado If your intention is to have `**/*.zip` traverse multiple levels of subdirectories then you really aught to label this code as Bash 4.X and explicitly set `globstar`. If your intention is to have it work on any version of Bash *but only traverse one level deep* then it would be more correct to use `for j in */*.zip`.  The extra `*` in `**` is extraneous in anything but Bash 4.X

Comment: @SiegeX Thanks for your feedback. I've added a comment about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Bash's parameter substitution:

```
bash-3.2$ for archive in folder/subfolder*/*.zip; do
    echo "Archive = ${archive}, Preview = ${archive%/*}/preview.zip"
done
Archive = folder/subfolder/archive.zip, Preview = folder/subfolder/preview.zip
Archive = folder/subfolder1/archive1.zip, Preview = folder/subfolder1/preview.zip
Archive = folder/subfolder2/archive2.zip, Preview = folder/subfolder2/preview.zip
Archive = folder/subfolder3/zip3.zip, Preview = folder/subfolder3/preview.zip
Archive = folder/subfolder4/zip4.zip, Preview = folder/subfolder4/preview.zip
```

Where `${archive%/*}` will strip off everything from the last `/` in `${archive}`.

This will allow you to verify the command that will run. Change this to:

```
mv "${archive}" "${archive%/*}/preview.zip"
```

... to rename the files (even if they have whitespace in their names).

Comment: he doesn't want the output files numbered. Just `preview.zip`

Comment: @SiegeX: I don't think this answer deserves a downvote. It was tested using `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)` and no `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Ok, so I see the problem. You really aren't using a bash 4.X feature (i.e. globstar) but there is also no difference between `folder/**/*.zip` and `folder/*/*.zip` on anything less than Bash 4.X. The extra `*` is extraneous. I'll remove the downvote if you edit.

Comment: @Johnsyweb This won't handle OP's last two files which are just `zip3.zip` and `zip4.zip`.

Comment: @SiegeX Looks like you are in no mood to take bad answers in `bash` tonight. :)

Comment: @Jonhsyweb Using `**` is very misleading because *globstar* exists in Bash 4.X.  In any version less than 4.X, `**` is the same as `*` which only traverses *one level deep*.  Whereas `**` in Bash 4.X traverses multiple levels just like `find` does.  Apparently the accepted answer has this same misconception. Also, I can't undo the downvote because it hasn't been edited.

Comment: @SiegeX: Thanks for pointing out that the OP changed the input since I tested and posted my answer. I have updated accordingly.

Comment: +1. I've liked all the answers in this post. Every answer has offered so much to learn. @SiegeX If you don't mind, can you please add the info you have shared about globstar in your answer, I am sure everyone would appreciate that information and would be worthy of an up-vote. At least one from me right away.

Comment: @JaypalSingh my downvotes are not personal (I undid 2 of 3 as they were remedied). Part of my problem was that I was (unintentionally) mislead to think that people were using `**` expecting recursive path transversal *because I know that's what it does in Bash 4.X*.  Those who don't know about `globstar` might start thinking that anywhere they put `**` will be recursive, when in reality it is not unless 1) They have Bash 4.x and 2) they did `shopt -s globstar` beforehand. Since `**` now has different syntactic meaning from `*`, being judicious about when to use which one is important.

Comment: @Johnsyweb my apologies, I thought I had removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file; do
  echo mv "$file" "${file%/*}/preview.zip"
done < <(find /folder -type f -name "archive*.zip")
```

***Note***: Remove the `echo` if the output looks sufficient and rerun the script to make the actual changes

Comment: Do we need `-print0` to handle filename with spaces in this case? Or will it work regardless?

Comment: @JaypalSingh Yes. To be completely immune to files with spaces in their name, or even files with other nasties like newlines the best approach would be to add `-print0` to the end of `find` and also use `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ...` I was a bit lazy about it with this one since the file names he wants to target are both known and well formed.  The best solution *is* the Bash 4.X version with globstar since you don't have to worry about all this stuff; but...you severely limit your audience since Bash 3.X has a much larger install base

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, but it's not fully tested:

```
find /folder -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec mv {}/archive*.zip {}/preview.zip \;
```

Working very strictly under your example, this *should* `find` all directories under `/folder`, with a maximum and minimum depth of 1 (i.e. only directories within `/folder`, since that seems to be what you want) and executes a `mv` command for a file under each.

Comment: This isn't going to work.  It's going to try to move the `archive*.zip` files into a directory named `<something>/preview.zip`

Comment: @SiegeX, it seems to work for me, with a basic test, minus the `*`. It looks like `find` doesn't want to pass that along as anything other than a literal `*`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb It def doesn't work if you try it, at least not for multiple files under the same directory that start with `archive`.  As Dan pointed out, it doesn't work as written with the `*`, but even if the shell *did* expand `*` prior to being `-exec` it would be no different than issuing the following command:  `mv /foo/archive1.zip /foo/archive2.zip /foo/archive3.zip foo/preview.zip`. Since `mv` uses the last argument as it's destination, it would try to do exactly what I said in my first comment, i.e. move three files into a directory called `/foo/archive.zip`

Comment: @SiegeX, for what it's worth, OP said specifically "Each folder also only has one zip in it so i don't have to work about overwriting and what not," so that part isn't a problem for this specific case. But the asterisks are.